# embedding python in a json file

Tags: python, json

In my application I am using json as the main API. It stores a set of commands to process files. This works great except part of my requirements is that I need to embed python.

I have a clunky solution, but am looking for a better one.

Here is an example of my approach:

```
{ "file key" :
     { "instruction1" : 
           { "commandList" : [
                {
                    "conditionalPythonBlock" : [
                         "myval = int(dict['count'])",
                         "retval = myval > 0"
                    ]
                }
           ]}
     }
}
```

I wrote a routine to collapse the "conditionalPythonBlock" into one multi line string which can then be executed.  The multi line approach is necessary for correct indentation.

The 'dict' variable in 'dict['mycount']' is local context in the parser of this file.

The retval is also a local variable in the context of the parser.

Anyone have a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your definition of _elegant_ and why are you unhappy with what you have?

Comment: do you want less layers in your JSON?

Comment: good question @DyZ.  I am concerned with the clunkiness of constructing this file given a block of python code.  I have to split all lines into an array.

Comment: Why not embed a block of code as a string? I mean the whole block as one string.

Comment: If you're worried about indentation, it's really not that hard to do reasonable things with a multi-line string. For example, you can use the same algorithm usually used with docstrings—splitlines, find the minimum left whitespace, cut that many spaces off each line (and then maybe indent all lines by X*4 for some X?)—and now you have something you can `exec` or store in a script or whatever you were planning to do with it.

Comment: But… is there a reason this needs to be human-readable source text? Depending on what you're actually trying to do, it could make more sense to just be a pickle reference to a function, or a token string, or marshaled compiled bytecode, or… I forget the name, but there's a lib that parses indents/dedents in Python code, turns them into some kind of sequence that can be passed through whitespace channels, and then converts them back for display and/or compile.

Comment: At any rate, if you can explain and/or show how you're building this block and how you're using it, it will probably be a lot easier to recommend improvements.

Comment: @abarnert, I like your idea about doc string processing..  Human readability is important right now because this is the only API for my tool. Eventually there will be a GUI layer, but that will be many sprints away..

Comment: @GlenWilson Well, presumably it’s human readability of the code in the editor/whatever interface, not in the JSON, right? So as long as your serialization is reversible, it doesn’t really matter. (And if doesn’t even have to be losslessly reversible; if you automatically clean the formatting, e.g., with `black`, then you just need to be able to reconstruct any code that matches the token stream, not exactly the original code.)

Comment: But meanwhile, IIRC, the algorithm used by things like doctest is just the `textwrap.dedent` function (which is probably worth mentioning because it seems like nobody knows about it unless they came to Python from Tcl in the stone ages).

Answer (score 1):

I think one very good answer here is to use YAML instead of JSON.

[PyYaml documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

The above example becomes:

```
file key :
   instruction1 : 
       - commands : 
                conditionalPythonBlock : |
                     myval = int(dict['count'])
                     retval = myval > 0
```

Much more readable, and the script section can just be copied in.